Sequelize typescript NO association methods
I don't think my problem is the most difficult, but I haven't really been able to make any progress with it for some time.
What is my problem ?
I use sequelize with typescript in my backend, and I want to create associations between tables / models (many-to-many / m:n). After creating these associations, it seems that I cannot access the "magic methods" (i.e. the methods generated by sequelize to make the association easier to use).
// association between tasks and employees was defined

const task = await DB.Tasks.findByPk(1) 
// task.addEmployee() or such methods doesnt exist! 

Using sequelize v6.37.2
What have I tried ?
Before we get to my code, I would like to give you a little important information first.
console.log(mymodel.associations) // works, no error  

will return my definied asscoation. I have also searched on github for a repository that might use a similar structure to my models (official sequelize docs template) but to no avail. I tried to stick to the official sequelize docs:
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/
My code
Here is one of my models (the other one has the same structure):
// Task is a simple interface containing all attributes
export type TaskCreationAttributes = Optional<Task, "id">

export class TaskModel extends Model<Task, TaskCreationAttributes> {
    declare id: number
    declare name: string
    declare description: string
}

export default function (sequelize: Sequelize): typeof TaskModel {
    TaskModel.init(
        {
            id: {
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            },
            name: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            },
            description: {
                allowNull: true,
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            } 
        },
        {
            tableName: "tasks",
            sequelize,
        },
    )

    

    TaskModel.belongsToMany(EmployeeModel, { through: "task_positions"})
    EmployeeModel.belongsToMany(TaskModel, { through: "task_positions"})

    return TaskModel
}


Hi, do you solve the problem?

You need to declare such "magic" methods explicitly using provided mixin interfaces from Sequelize (see the link you mentioned):
declare getEmployees: BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin<Emplyee>;


Thanks for your answer! After defining this method, the code firstly seems correct. But after executing this line of code, it says:
await task.getEmployees()
// Error after executing:  task.getEmployees is not a function

Did you check at runtime what methods actually task has?
